# C-1 Visa validity period after issuance

Tags: visas, visa-expiration

Can anyone advise how long a US C-1 transit visa is valid from the date of issuance?  I assume it is multi-entry since I will need to transit in both directions.  I just need to know how far in advance we can apply for the visa.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends in part on your nationality.  You can look up the default validity period at https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/Visa-Reciprocity-and-Civil-Documents-by-Country.html/.

The consular officer may however issue the visa for a shorter period, but this is uncommon as far as I know.

Since the visa may be valid for up to 10 years (for some nationalities), and the fee for B and C visas is the same, you might consider applying for a B-2 visa instead.